# font family "times you roman" shows no ü/ä/ö

Tags: fonts, font-family

for my website i load with css and @font-face the fontfamily times new roman. The font family actually loads and works. But letters like ü/ä/ö are shown as symbols. How can i fix this?

best regrads

tom

Comment: Have you considered ascii codes? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472621/So-You-Want-An-ASCII-Code-Huh.htm

Comment: Is your web page actually encoded in something like ISO-8859-1 when the instruction (either HTTP header or meta tag) to the client specifies it is encoded as UTF-8?